# How to make a [u8; 11] out of "hello world"?

Tags: rust, casting

This works:

```
pub const HELLO_WORLD: [u8] = "hello world".to_string().as_bytes();
```

but I need it to be a `[u8; 11]` so that I can do simple byte matches, such as:

```
if buf[4..15] != HELLO_WORLD {
```

(This is to check "magic" strings in a file format.)

Is there a way of declaring:

```
pub const HELLO_WORLD: [u8; 11] = "hello world".to_string().as_bytes();
```

that does not cause an error?  (An `&[u8; 11]` would also be fine, it's having a type with a fixed length which is important.)

Comment: Are you aware of the syntax `b"hello world"`? (which gives a `&[u8; 11]` but that seems good enough for your usecase).

Comment: "This works" no, actually it doesn't, but if you remove the spurious `to_string()` it does. Moreover, the only problem with `buf[4..15] != HELLO_WORLD` would seem to be that it's comparing a reference to a non-reference, which you can easily solve by comparing to `*HELLO_WORLD` or `&buf[4..15]`. Is removing the `&` the point of your question?

Comment: @mcarton Thanks, I hadn't encountered `b""`.  If you make this an answer I'll accept it.  @trent Yes, I made a mistake, now fixed.

Comment: I now have `pub const HELLO_WORLD: &[u8; 11] = b"hello world";` and `if &buf[4..15] != HELLO_WORLD {`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rust has byte string literals, which are similar to string literals but prefixed with a `b`. `b"hello world"` will give you a `&[u8; 11]`.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that, since `[u8; 11]` is sized, you can dereference to get an actual array: `const HELLO_WORLD: [u8; 11] = *b"hello world";` (which you cannot do with a `&str` or `&[u8]`)